# Java web app serve both secure and insecure resource

Tags: java, web-applications, ssl, security

I am writing a Java web app (spring 3.2).

Basically, I have several sites that need to access my web service. These sites are a mixture of both secured (ssl) and insecured. I have an endpoint /validate/{id} that should respond to both secured requests

```
 (https://localhost:8443/ws/validate/123 and http://localhost:8080/ws/validate/123)
```

How do I do this? I've added

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ws</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

to my web.xml, but that only forces ssl ( calls to 8080 get a 302 FOUND response with a Location header pointing to 8443.

How do I allow both secured and insecured requests on the same endpoint (with different ports)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
```

seems to have done the trick...